# Active Model Serializers: How to pass options to a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

If I have a collection of something, say Widgets, and I'm using Active Model Serializers to serialize the collection of Widgets, how do I pass instance_options to a collection?

```
render json: @widgets, count: 40
```

I tried the above and I can't seem to get `count: 40` in my `instance_options`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you can pass locals. `render json: @widgets, locals: { count: 40 }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `@instance_options[:count]` in method of WidgetsSerializer.

In controller:

```
render json: @widgets, count: 40
```

For exmaple,

```
class WidgetsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :count

  def count
    @instance_options[:count] #=> 40
  end
end
```